# Print all hidden locator of drop down element values and select one by one of react bootstrap

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

We have react bootstrap app which has Dropdown field, trying to get Xpath and select drop down value however when selected drop down value html doesn't show locator or it has hidden element locator as shown in the picture.

Here in the picture, `<input tag.. has aria-activedescendant="ch...demo-option-**0**">` for the first drop down value, if selected second drop down manually then it will change to `<  "ch...demo-option-**1**">`

But this locator kind of hidden, unless mouse over on the drop down element this demo-option-0 doesn't show.

How to find this drop down element and get all values to print, select all check boxes.

[image]

Comment: share drop down HTML in text format

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. in text format: <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="checkboxes-tags-demo" placeholder="Select" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="">                               If observed here, when tried to get html of selected element it goes off.

Comment: this is just for Select web element, I don't see any option in it ? add binding language tag also

Comment: <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot jss3617 MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-adornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput-adornedEnd"><input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="checkboxes-tags-demo" placeholder="Select" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="">                                          under div>child node input

Comment: Is URL public or private ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, it is private.